# GAN implementation _ ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I am implementing a simple 2-layer GAN (Generative Adversarial Network), but I am having an implementation issue. I get the value error (ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.) and looking at other questions with the same error, I think the issue is the type issue between numpy ndarray and Tensorflow tensor when using a feed_dict in session.run(). However, I really can't find why mine causes this error. I've tried converting tensor -> ndarray and vice versa, but none of the methods seem to work. The error message points at the line `Z: np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[mini_batch, Z_dim])` (in last code block).

```
mini_batch = 128
Z_dim = 100

Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100])
```

...

```
def generator(z):
    G_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, G_W1) + G_b1)
    G_log_prob = tf.matmul(G_h1, G_W2) + G_b2
    G_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(G_log_prob)
    return G_prob

def discriminator(x):
    D_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, D_W1) + D_b1)
    D_logit = tf.matmul(D_h1, D_W2) + D_b2
    D_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(D_logit)
    return D_prob, D_logit
```

...

```
    G_sample = generator(Z)
    D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X)
    D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

    D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real) + tf.log(1.0 - D_fake))
    G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_fake))

    D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(D_loss, var_list=theta_D)
```

...

```
        _, D_loss_curr = sess.run([D_solver, D_loss], feed_dict={
    X: fake_tweets, 
    Z: np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[mini_batch, Z_dim])
    })
```

I am trying to train the generator to produce fake tweets.

Comment: Z seems to be ok, what about X, did you check their sizes?

Comment: I think so. X is a placeholder with shape (None, 20) and fake_tweets is a numpy ndarray of shape (128, 20). 
  
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_words_in_tweet]). Could it be the issue of types between X and fake_tweets? If so, how can I fix it? I've tried tf.convert_to_tensor(fake_tweets) but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Is fake_tweets not float?. Its a string?. Then you need to create a dictionary where you map the string to a number and then pass it to your network.

Comment: fake_tweets is a ndarray with shape (128, 20), not a string.

Comment: ndarray of type float?. If not cast it to float using astype()

Comment: it is an ndarray of type float. I've vectorized words. It's actually a ndarray of ndarray of floats

Comment: How can I represent a vector (eg [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ]) as a float without ranking them? What I mean by ranking is that plain integer position of '1' in the vector will not accurately represent the vector because for instance 10 > 1. Or is that not a problem? I remember reading that it can be a problem..

Comment: Share the code (or a self contained snippet) if you want me to debug.

Comment: Its missing file.txt